# htaccess change '=' to ','

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

how to change  '?' to ','

this is now

```
index.php?page=2&search=stackoverflow
```

i want it to be like this

```
index.php/page,2/search,stackoverflow
```

any idea?

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index.php/page,([0-9]+)/search,([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ index.php?page=$1&search=$2 [QSA,L]
```

Should work. I tested it. Will work assuming "page" is a number, and "search" is a character which matches a-zA-Z0-9